# How to add unsubscribe link in mail when using Bcc

Tags: php, email, yii2

I am using the following code in controller to send newsletters to subscribers

```
$body           =    $model->letter_content;


$to_email       =   'admin@site.in';


for($i=0;$i<count($msg_to);$i++){
            $maitto         =   $msg_to[$i];
               if($maitto != '')
                $headers       .=   'Bcc:'.$maitto."\r\n";
        }

 mail($to_email,$subject,$body,$headers);
```

the variable **'$msg_to'** contains all subscriber list as array.
The variable **'$body'** has the saved static newsletter body..
I am sending the mail to admin and adding all subscribers as **'Bcc'** as I dont want to use mail function inside the for loop to send individually to all subscribers.
Now I want to add a link in the mail to allow subscribers to unsubscribe..If i was sending mail individually inside the for loop i could have used something like this inside loop before **mail()** function

```
$body .= '<a href="unsubscribe.php?id=$maitto">UNSUBSCRIBE</a>'
```

But since here i am using 'Bcc' is there any other way to do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You basically have two options in this case:

1. You could have the unsubscribe link take them to a page where they enter their email address.
2. You can find a way to start looping through each user to send the email individually, like you said you don't want to do.

One email can only have one set of content. Therefore, no matter how many people you send it to they all will get the same email.

If you really feel strongly about using the BCC field for everyone, option one will work fine.